# Grid renders different in page vs. fiddle

Tags: html, css, blazor-server-side

I want to create a square grid with HTML/CSS. I have the following code, which does just that, but it clips the sides and bottom, when I use it in my actual page compared to my fiddle.

The raw HTML/CSS looks like this:

**CSS**

```
.grid {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: black;
  max-width: 90vh;
  max-height: 90vh;
  padding: 1px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}
.box {
  background: white;
  margin: 1px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.box::after {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
.box .inner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="box"><div class="inner">0</div></div>
        <div class="box"><div class="inner">1</div></div>
        <div class="box"><div class="inner">2</div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="box"><div class="inner">20</div></div>
        <div class="box"><div class="inner">21</div></div>
        <div class="box"><div class="inner">22</div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="box"><div class="inner">40</div></div>
        <div class="box"><div class="inner">41</div></div>
        <div class="box"><div class="inner">42</div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The real page uses a 50x50 grid, which I didn't want to bother you with, but check out [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BuildItBusk/69mpf0a4/6/).

In the fiddle it looks really nice, like this:

[image: Grid in fiddle]

But when it goes into the real page, it looks like this (clipped a bit, to avoid cluttering):

[image: Grid in actual page]

I am aware that the actual page also includes stuff like a navigation bar, etc. which takes up some space. But that is the same in the fiddle I guess? Isn't `90vh` supposed to take up 90% of the space available to it?

If anyone wants to generate the grid, I am doing that with Blazor (server side):

```
@page "/grid"

<div class="grid">
@for (int r = 0; r < _numRows; r++) {
    <div class="row">
    @for (int c = 0; c < _numCols; c++) {
        int rr = r; // Row of the specific div
        int cc = c; // Column of the specifc div
        <div class="box"><div class="inner">@(c + r * _numRows)</div></div>
    }
    </div>
}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a clash with [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/), which also happens to have a `.row` element. So by changing the name of my custom row to `.gridrow` it worked as in the fiddle.

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="gridrow">
    ...etc.
```